# SparseBooleanArray - deleted key, goes back when view recycled in Listview Custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've a Custom Adapter, in each item view i have like and dislike button. I'm using SparseBooleanArray to mapping integer to boolean. In getView of my custom adapter, I've defined these SparseBooleanArray:

```
    private final SparseBooleanArray LikedPositions     = new SparseBooleanArray();
    private final SparseBooleanArray DislikedPositions  = new SparseBooleanArray();
```

then, based on data that retrieved by API, I fill them like this:

```
    if (Like_with_user == true){
            LikedPositions.put(position, true);
    }

    if (Dislike_with_user == true){
        DislikedPositions.put(position, true);
    }
```

and right after this step, I set background of like and dislike buttons:

```
    if(LikedPositions.get(position)){
        holder.video_Like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_pressed);
    }else{
        holder.video_Like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_normal);
    }


    if(DislikedPositions.get(position)){
        holder.video_Dislike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dislike_pressed);
    }else{
        holder.video_Dislike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dislike_normal);
    }
```

after this, I set OnClickListener to like and DisLike buutons:

```
    holder.video_Like.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View like) {

            int likeposition        = (Integer) like.getTag(R.string.Position);
            RelativeLayout layout   = (RelativeLayout) like.getParent();
            Button BtnLike          = (Button) layout.getChildAt(0);
            Button BtnDislike       = (Button) layout.getChildAt(1);

            if(DislikedPositions.get(likeposition)){
                BtnDislike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dislike_normal);
                DislikedPositions.delete(likeposition);
                System.out.println("Dislike: "+DislikedPositions);
            }

            if(LikedPositions.get(likeposition)){
                BtnLike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_normal);
                LikedPositions.delete(likeposition);
                System.out.println("like: "+LikedPositions);
            }else{
                scale.setDuration(300);
                scale.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
                BtnLike.startAnimation(scale);
                BtnLike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_pressed);
                LikedPositions.put(likeposition, true);
                System.out.println("like: "+LikedPositions);
            }
        }
    });
```

Problem is Here, when i clicked the button, everthing work perefctly, key add and delete!
but when I scroll listview and view recycled, deleted key getting back back!!
Why?!

Ps: I set these tags to like and dislike buttons to:

```
    holder.video_Like.setTag(R.string.Position, position);
    holder.video_Like.setTag(R.string.Video_ID, VIDEO_ID);
```

**UPDATE: My custom adapter getview:**

```
    private final SparseBooleanArray LikedPositions     = new SparseBooleanArray();
    private final SparseBooleanArray DislikedPositions  = new SparseBooleanArray();

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        User_Session            = new SessionManagement(mActivity);

        View vi             = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder   = null;

        HashMap<String, String> mVideo  = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mVideo              = mData.get(position);

        VIDEO_URL           = mVideo.get("VIDEO_URL");
        VIDEO_ID            = mVideo.get("VIDEO_ID");
        LIKE_W_USER         = mVideo.get("LIKE_W_USER");
        DISLIKE_W_USER      = mVideo.get("DISLIKE_W_USER");     
        Like_with_user      = Boolean.parseBoolean(LIKE_W_USER);
        Dislike_with_user   = Boolean.parseBoolean(DISLIKE_W_USER);


        final String videoUid           = mVideo.get("uid");

        if(convertView == null) {
            vi      = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_row, null);
            holder  = new ViewHolder();
            holder.video_Like           = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.video_Like);
            holder.video_Dislike        = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.video_disLike);
            vi.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        holder.video_Like.setTag(R.string.Position, position);
        holder.video_Like.setTag(R.string.Video_ID, VIDEO_ID);
        holder.video_Dislike.setTag(R.string.Position, position);
        holder.video_Dislike.setTag(R.string.Video_ID, VIDEO_ID);

        if(User_Session.isLoggedIn() != true){


            holder.video_Comment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LoginWarn();
                }
            });

            holder.video_Like.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LoginWarn();
                }
            });
            holder.video_Dislike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LoginWarn();
                }
            });

        }else{

            HashMap<String, String> user    = User_Session.GetUserDetails();
            final String User_TOKEN         = user.get(SessionManagement.KEY_USERTOKEN);

            if (Like_with_user == true){                                                    // Check that user liked this video before or not
                LikedPositions.put(position, true);
            }

            if (Dislike_with_user == true){                                                 // Check that user disliked this video before or not
                DislikedPositions.put(position, true);
            }

            if(LikedPositions.get(position)){                                               // Highlight Like Sign if user liked it before
                holder.video_Like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_pressed);
            }else{
                holder.video_Like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_normal);
            }

            if(DislikedPositions.get(position)){                                            // Highlight dislike Sign if user disliked it before
                holder.video_Dislike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dislike_pressed);
            }else{
                holder.video_Dislike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dislike_normal);
            }


            holder.video_Like.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int position            = (Integer) v.getTag(R.string.Position);
                    RelativeLayout layout   = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
                    Button BtnLike          = (Button) layout.getChildAt(0);
                    Button BtnDislike       = (Button) layout.getChildAt(1);

                    Ion.with(mActivity).load(Constants.Like_URL+v.getTag(R.string.Video_ID)+"/?token="+User_TOKEN).asString()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>(){

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {

                            if(e != null){
                                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Sorry, Error Happened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                    });

                    if(DislikedPositions.get(position)){
                        BtnDislike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dislike_normal);
                        DislikedPositions.delete(position);
                    }

                    if(LikedPositions.get(position)){
                        BtnLike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_normal);
                        LikedPositions.delete(position);
                    }else{
                        scale.setDuration(300);
                        scale.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
                        BtnLike.startAnimation(scale);
                        BtnLike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_pressed);
                        LikedPositions.put(position, true);
                    }
                }
            });


            holder.video_Dislike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int position            = (Integer) v.getTag(R.string.Position);
                    RelativeLayout layout   = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
                    Button BtnLike          = (Button) layout.getChildAt(0);
                    Button btnDislike       = (Button) layout.getChildAt(1);

                    Ion.with(mActivity).load(Constants.Dislike_URL+v.getTag(R.string.Video_ID)+"/?token="+User_TOKEN).asString()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>(){

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {

                            if(e != null){
                                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Sorry, Error Happened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                    });

                    if(LikedPositions.get(position)){
                        BtnLike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_normal);
                        LikedPositions.delete(position);
                    }

                    if(DislikedPositions.get(position)){
                        btnDislike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dislike_normal);
                        DislikedPositions.delete(position);
                    }else{
                        scale.setDuration(300);
                        scale.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
                        btnDislike.startAnimation(scale);
                        btnDislike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dislike_pressed);
                        DislikedPositions.put(position, true);
                    }
                }
            });

        }






        // we're near the end of the list adapter, so load more items
        if (position >= getCount() - 1){
            mSwipe.setRefreshing(true);
            loadmore();
        }




        return vi;
}
```

Comment: Please show the entire code of your getView method.  Sounds like you aren't handling it correctly.  Also, why have two SparseArrays when one can easily do the same thing?

Comment: @JaySoyer I added, please check this out.

Comment: In your `getView()` method where exactly do you set the state from those `SparseBooleanArrays`?

Comment: @Luksprog, Firstly in `Like_with_user == true`and `Dislike_with_user == true` statement derived from API, secondly when like button or dislike button click.

Comment: Do you update the mVideo object in the onClickListener of those like and dislike buttons?

Comment: @Luksprog No, should I do it?

Comment: Well if you don't update it you don't get the initial `Like_with_user` values and the same status when the view is recycled?

Comment: @Luksprog How Should I do that? :(

Comment: In the OnClickListeners get a reference to the mVideo Hashmap and update the values for the `LIKE_W_USER` keys for that row.

Comment: @Luksprog You know what, when my buttons are in normal state, and user click on one of them, and scroll listview, everything work as a charm. but when one of them be in pressed state, and user click on that or click on another button...everything goes wrong! While in first situation I didn't update mVideo but by recycling added information does not go! like deleted item getting back!! :(

Comment: @Luksprog yeah I know that its can be weird but can you provide a snippet code?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59298/discussion-between-may3am-and-luksprog).

Comment: @Luksprog You were right, I should update my base resource, of course, by updating key in mVideo i didn't get answer, but when I update mVideo `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` with this `mData.get(likeposition).put("LIKE_W_USER", "false");` everything work perfectly :D...thank you man

Answer (score 0):

Wow, there's a lot going on in that `getView()`.  Off the bat, the following looks really wrong.

```
 // we're near the end of the list adapter, so load more items
 if (position >= getCount() - 1){
     mSwipe.setRefreshing(true);
     loadmore();
 }
```

The `getView()` method can be called 3-4 times per position number. It may or may not be called for all items when first displaying to the screen.  So determining when to load more items into the adapter here is really bad. Considering you said problems don't arise till you start scrolling...I'd say this might be your culprit.

What you should do instead is attach an `OnScollListener` to the `ListView` and check the `ListView.getLastVisiblePosition()` against your adapter count to determine when to load more.

Also, before applying this fix, I'd just remove that segment of code and see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: I removed this segment and try, but it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: You know what I think @Luksprog is right, I should update mVideo's LIKE_W_USER key.